# Meteor: EJSON is not defined

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use a private JSON file to add some simple template documents to the mongo collection if it is empty:

```
if (Passions.find().count() === 0) {
  mockPassions = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("mockups/passions.json"));
  _.each(mockPassions.passions, function(passion) {
    return Passions.insert(passion);
  });
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> ReferenceError: EJSON is not defined

Does anyone have any clue? I'm using Meteor 0.6.5. 
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to bring `EJSON` up to the global namespace via

```
meteor add ejson
```

In meteor 0.6.5 unless you explicitly tell it to, packages are namespaced into `package`

Comment: Thanks! Btw, EJSON should be lowercase: meteor add ejson

Answer (score 0):

Considering Latest Meteor **1.6**, you can follow below steps:

A. First Approach [*Independent of the meteor restart/stop/start*]

1. Edit `.meteor/packages` file and add 'ejson' to end of the file

B. Second Approach

1. Stop Server if already running by pressing `ctrl+c`
2. Run command `meteor add ejson`
3. Restart Server using command `meteor`

Comment: or use another terminal window to add